# Populate facebook feed dialog message box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small game in my website, and i want people to post their best time in facebook. To do this, i made an app, and then use the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=363262997057304&name=Myname&link=http://www.mywebsite.com&redirect_uri=http://www.mywebsite.com&description=MyDescription

But i dont know how could I do it to populate the message field. what could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to prefill the message field, asper Facebook, unless from a natural flow, such as a user typing in a textbox and sending to the message field on a submit.  You should use the description, caption fields for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The message parameter is deprecated,
also you can use FBJS API to post in a user feed,

```
function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
        method:      'feed',
        link:        'https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/',
        picture:     'https://domain.tld/75x75.jpg',
        name:        'TITLE',
        caption:     'CAPTION',
        description: 'My Score: '+score
    };
    FB.ui(obj);
}
```

but you have to ask the user for `publish_stream` permissions first.

Comment: The publish_stream permission is now deprecated as per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a game app, all you need to do is to publish their score using the games score API described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/

> **Scores and Achievements**
>
> Scores and achievements APIs are built on Open Graph and receive the
>   same distribution points that all Open Graph stories do - Ticker,
>   Newsfeed and Timeline. In addition to these scores and achievements
>   also benefit from built in aggregations and stories that have been
>   designed by Facebook.